# 3次元配列を2次元配列に変換

Tags: python, python3

```py
Z=[[array([1,2,3]),array([9,8]),array([0,2,5,6])],
[array([4,5,6]),array([7,2]),array([1,2,2,1])],
[array([10,6,8]),array([17,11]),array([15,0,1,3])]]
```

```py
Z=[array([1,2,3,9,8,0,2,5,6]),
array([4,5,6,7,2,1,2,2,1]),
array([10,6,8,17,11,15,0,1,3])]
```

上記のように変換したいです。
この例Zのサイズは(3,3)で中身が(3,2,4)ですが、実際のZのサイズは、(1947806,17)でその中身は(61,93,43,36,,,)となるくらい大きなリスト（変換後のZのサイズは(1947806)で中身が726となる予定）ですので、Memory Errorとならない方法をご教示いただければ大変助かります。
（Memory Errorとなる方法であれば自分でも回すことはできました）

※追記
下記でアドバイス頂いたmap()ですと、変換後のZをその後ループ文で毎回読み込む必要があるため膨大な所要時間となってしまいます。
（かれこれ20時間位、メモリとディスクをフルに使用しています）
他に方法がございましたらご教示いただけますと大変助かります。
参考として、Zを変換したあとは以下のようなコードとなっております。

```
Factor=[]
for w in range(len(Result)): #len(Result)はlen(Z2)と同じく1947806
    Z2=map(np.concatenate, Z)
    x = np.array(list(Z2)[w])[:, np.newaxis]
    y=(x*yy).sum() #yyは(726,8)のデータフレーム
    z=np.sum(np.array(np.abs((y-b)))) #bは(1,8)のデータフレーム
    Factor.append([y['A'],y['B'],y['C'],y['D'],z,zz[w],xx[w]]) #zz,xxは長さ1947806のデータシリーズ
```

Comment: [numpy.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.4/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) を使うのはどうでしょうか。`map(numpy.concatenate, Z)`

Comment: @metropolis 様、ありがとうございます。len()やprint()を使って取得したいデータに変換できたことが確認できました。
このmap()を使って最終的に求めたいものを現在ループ文で計算させておりますが、Memory Errorが出ないことを祈るばかりです。

Comment: ええと、ループの内部で毎回 Z2 を計算していますが、それは必要ですか？ つまり、Z2 はループの外側で一度だけ導出すればよいのではないでしょうか？

Comment: もちろんはじめはループの外側において実行したのですが、w=1でエラーが出てしまいました。なのでループの中に入れなければいけないと思いましたが、間違っておりますでしょうか。

Comment: 状況がよく分からないのですが、`Z2 = list(map(np.concatenate, Z))` として、`x = Z2[w][:, np.newaxis]` にするとどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: ああ、なるほど、Python3 をお使いなのですね？

Comment: はい、Python3でございます。

Comment: Python3ですとmapはiteratorを返します(Python2ではlist)。そのため、2回目の `list(Z2)` では空リストが返る事になってしまいます。データを適当に作って書いた[コード](https://paiza.io/projects/e/ELNF0mCr6neEySBYHGNGNw)ですが、参考までにどうぞ。

Comment: @metropolis 様、ご丁寧に書いていただきありがとうございます。大変参考になります。実行し、トラブルがあったらまた相談させてください。